# Volume element in 4 dimensions

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

[image]

I was reading the book called "Gravitation: Foundations and Frontier" by T.Padmanabhan, there in chapter 1 he defined the 3-volume element of a 3-surface in 4-dimensions, as shown in the above Image in (1.58), I understand why this definition works, but I want to know the motive behind such a construction.

My question is, assuming I wanted to write the volume element of a 3-surface in 4-dimension, how could I have guessed/constructed/ arrive at the form in (1.58)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two pieces in this construction. The volume element in 3 dimensions, by definition, is given by the *top* (*differential*) *form*
$$v = \pm \text{d}x \wedge \text{d}y \wedge \text{d}z = \frac{\pm 1}{3!} \epsilon_{ijk}~\text{d}x^i~\text{d}x^j~\text{d}x^k,$$
where the $\pm$ indicates a choice of orientation. The factor
$$\frac{\partial(x^j, x^k, x^l)}{\partial(a,b,c)}$$
is the Jacobian factor associated with the coordinate transformation $(x^i, x^k, x^l)\mapsto (a,b,c)$, and is defined by
$$\text{d}x^i~\text{d}x^k~\text{d}x^l = \frac{\partial(x^j, x^k, x^l)}{\partial(a,b,c)} \text{d}a~\text{d}b~\text{d}c.$$
Combining the two gives the desired expression.